# Android notifications for read inbox messages

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

I am running Stack Exchange Android app version **1.0.63**.

I had disconnected my phone from Wi-Fi and after that, I browsed Stack Exchange from my Laptop and received a bunch of inbox messages. I replied to them and the top bar on any relevant Stack Exchange site showed no new messages.

I reconnected my phone to Wi-Fi, and in the past 10 minutes I have received about 20 old notifications. The app itself shows them as read, but I still get the notifications. On clicking the notification, the inbox opens, but no message is highlighted.

This happened before, but I ignored it then. Also, Stack Exchange on my iPad doesn't suffer from this.

Comment: @Tim that one's resolved, but issue persists.

Comment: That one doesn't seem resolved... It's the same bug and was asked 9 hours before yours...